# The term 'Select-AzureRMSubscription' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet with VSTS Build Step Failure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

This just started happening.  When I remote to the agent and run those commands, they run fine.  This has been running fine for months.  I've rebooted the machine as well.  Any thoughts on why?

[image]

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzurePowerShell

Comment: If this helps, when i change this to Hosted2017 it works fine.  It must be something with the agent on the custom build machine.  This worked last week, no changes, just stopped working.  sigh.

Comment: Try to update Azure PowerShell on that machine and try again https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-5.4.0. On the other hand, you can try to change agent service account to your account and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Is it running the correct version of the ARM powershell?

From the output you could see the version of the powershell module it is rubning.

Comment: this looks more like a comment tbh

Comment: you can delete the answer.